# Implementation of file "save" like Notepad

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I want to create a text editor (using java/swing) like notepad. For this I need the implementation of saving file. mean if the user clicks on "save" first time then the dialog should appear for taking file-name, file-extension. But if he clicks again on same "save" button then the file should save without appearing the "save-dialog-box".

Thanx

Comment: Are you asking: (a) how to open the save dialog box, or (b) how to *avoid* opening the save dialog box if the user has already saved the file once?

Comment: Think of it as if: clicking on "save" the first time, *actually* opens the "save as" dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a singleton `JFileChooser`, it will hold the last-selected file path/name until you pop the dialog again. Doing it this way might prevent filename synchronization issues you might encounter otherwise. For example, the user saves the first time, enters the filename he wants to save as, then a minute later changes his mind and decides to Save As to a new filename. If you use a singleton `JFileChooser`, you can just reference it when performing the actual save because it will always have the most recently selected filename.

Answer (score 5):

Just keep track of the chosen name within your application. If your application has stored a name, re-use it for subsequent saves.

Answer (score 1):

You can just look whether the file was already named. You probably start with an "Unnamed1" file in the beginning. This is where you want to display the save dialog. In case you opened a file that already existed or you already saved the file you would know its name and can save directly.

Answer (score 0):

For general help on using the Java File chooser check out the Sun Tutorial

[How to Use File Choosers](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html)